# Left Join with AND is still filtering rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.cardNo, acc.accountId
FROM card c
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON c.accId = acc.id
```

The above query returns 500 rows. In the above query I am retrieving all cards. I am pretending to see that cards which do not have an account (just as an example), will return NULL instead of an accountId.

Then I wanted to get all cards, and only the accountId of countries registered in Europe. So I still wanted 500 cards, so I tried the following:

```
SELECT c.cardNo, acc.accountId
FROM card c
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON c.accId = acc.id AND acc.registrationContinent = 'EU'
```

Yet to my surprise, I am getting 300 rows (and not 500), the above is also equivalent as if I had a WHERE clause.

Could someone kindly explain why the LEFT JOIN is not returning all the records from the card table?

Comment: Does all the 500 cards has registration continent as 'EU'

Comment: If you just do a `SELECT * FROM card`, how many rows do you get? Despite the name, is it possible for there to be *mutliple* rows in `accounts` that have the *same* `id` value?

Comment: Can u jst see distinct registration_continent from the above query..

Comment: And no, it's not like a where clause. If you put `acc.registrationContinent = 'EU'` in a where clause, you won't get the cards without account. While your second query gives also these results.

Answer (score 2):

because you're filtering the accounts which are not in 'EU'.

If you want a NULL value in acc.accountid when account.registrationContinent  is not `EU`, you may do

```
SELECT c.cardNo, 
case when acc.registrationContinent = 'EU' then acc.accountId else NULL end
FROM card c
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON c.accId = acc.id
```

But I think you have many accounts by card, some with EU, some without EU.

So with your second query, you still have all your cards (I can bet that you have less than 500 different cards and probably less then 300 different cards).

The first query will return multiple time the same card, if it has more than one account (each time with a different account).

Just check

```
select count(*) from card
```

to see how many different cards do you have.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified a condition in the join, this will now be part of how the tables are matched together. To get the results you want you can use a subquery to filter the reulst you join to your cards. Like this:

```
SELECT c.cardNo,
    acc.accountId
FROM card c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT accountId
    FROM accounts
    WHERE registrationContinent = 'EU'
    ) acc
    ON c.accId = acc.id
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have condition in join statement, 1st data is filtered, then the Join occurs.
When you give condition in WHERE, first the join Occurs, then data is filtered.

The below case may help you..

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(5), DEPID INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE (DEPID INT, DEPNAME VARCHAR(5),COUNTRY VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @A VALUES (1,'JIT',101),(2,'PAT',101),(3,'JOM',101),(4,'MARK',102),(5,'FAL',103)
INSERT INTO @B VALUES (101,'HR','IND'),(102,'ACC','IND'),(103,'OPER','US')

SELECT      * FROM @A
SELECT      * FROM @B
```

**Result**

[image]

```
SELECT      *
FROM        @A A 
LEFT JOIN   @B B ON A.DEPID = B.DEPID

SELECT      *
FROM        @A A 
LEFT JOIN   @B B ON A.DEPID = B.DEPID AND B.COUNTRY = 'US'
```

**Result**

[image]